# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-kms

I want to integrate GCP key management service.I am using java-11 for my spring boot application.Project dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-kms</artifactId>
    <version>2.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=noottverk
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:noottverk-0fc5045048a2.json
spring.cloud.gcp.kms.enabled=true
```

my service:

```
package org.noottverk.backend.services;

import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKeyName;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AesGcpKmsService {
    private final String projectId;
    private final String locationId;
    private final String keyRingId;
    private final String cryptoKeyId;

    // Inject values from application.properties or any other configuration method
    public AesGcpKmsService(@Value("${gcp.kms.projectId}") String projectId,
                            @Value("${gcp.kms.locationId}") String locationId,
                            @Value("${gcp.kms.keyRingId}") String keyRingId,
                            @Value("${gcp.kms.cryptoKeyId}") String cryptoKeyId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.keyRingId = keyRingId;
        this.cryptoKeyId = cryptoKeyId;
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(projectId+" "+locationId+" "+keyRingId+" "+cryptoKeyId+" "+ plaintext.toString());
        // Create the KeyManagementServiceClient using try-with-resources to close it automatically
        try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
            // The CryptoKeyName represents the full path of the key
            CryptoKeyName cryptoKeyName = CryptoKeyName.of(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);
            System.out.println("cryptoKeyName: "+cryptoKeyName+ "plaintext: "+plaintext);

            // Encrypt the plaintext
            ByteString encrypted = client.encrypt(cryptoKeyName, ByteString.copyFrom(plaintext)).getCiphertext();
            return encrypted.toByteArray();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
        try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
            CryptoKeyName cryptoKeyName = CryptoKeyName.of(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

            // Decrypt the ciphertext
            ByteString decrypted = client.decrypt(cryptoKeyName, ByteString.copyFrom(ciphertext)).getPlaintext();
            return decrypted.toByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

When i submit a form it creates error like **nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub**